# Why Measure pass is skipped when adding a custom view in a thread?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, measure

I noticed the below difference in layout calls when working with custom views in Android. I have two custom views derived from FrameLayout inside a LinearLayout. The first FrameLayout is added in a non-UI thread using RunOnUiThread() method. The second FrameLayout is added using the UIThread.

Now the difference I notice is that the measure hits for the FrameLayout that is added directly using a UIThread is 2. Whereas the measure hits for the FrameLayout that is added from a Non-UIThread using RunOnUiThread() is 1. Usually in Android, the measure hits for a custom view is 2. But ***why does the second measure pass is skipped when adding the view using RunOnUiThread() option?***

***Does anyone know the reason for this difference in Layout passes when using threads in Xamarin.Android***? 
I have attached my MainActivity code for your reference:

***MainActivity.cs***

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var view = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.Linear);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                var threadView = new CustomViewInsideThread(this);
                view.AddView(threadView);
            });
        });

        var nonThreadView = new CustomViewOusideThread(this);
        view.AddView(nonThreadView);
    }
}

public class CustomViewInsideThread : FrameLayout
{
    public CustomViewInsideThread(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
    int hitCount = 0;
    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        hitCount++;
        Console.WriteLine("Measure hit " + hitCount.ToString() + "time");
    }
}

public class CustomViewOusideThread : FrameLayout
{
    public CustomViewOusideThread(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
    int hitCount = 0;
    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        hitCount++;
        Console.WriteLine("Measure hit " + hitCount.ToString() + "time");
    }
}
```

***Main.axml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Linear"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Maybe not related to your question, but did you notice, that you call `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);` twice!? And: could you please add your Main.axml ?

Comment: Hi @Sven-MichaelStübe,
Sorry, this is by mistake I have added it twice has no effects regarding this issue. I have added the Main.axml code.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `RunOnUiThread`. You tricked yourself, because it is a **timing issue**. The measurement is called twice, because the view is added before android has measured everything properly. This means, that android will call the measurement multiple times.

You can reproduce this, when you add your view on a button click or wait a bit on the UI thread (non blocking).

```
[Activity(Label = "App3", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        var btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);

        // add view on button click
        btn.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var view = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.Linear);
            var nonThreadView = new CustomViewOusideThread(this);
            view.AddView(nonThreadView);
        };
    }

    protected async override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        var view = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.Linear);


        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                var threadView = new CustomViewInsideThread(this);
                view.AddView(threadView);
            });
        });

        await Task.Delay(1000); // non blocking wait on UI thread
        var nonThreadView = new CustomViewOusideThread(this);
        view.AddView(nonThreadView);

    }
}
```

Both will give you:

> 03-14 16:33:15.990 I/mono-stdout(31936): UI Measure hit 1time

Comment: Hi @Sven-Michael Stube,
Thanks for the explanation. Does this means that removing or reducing the amount of sleep time in my code should fix the issue?

Comment: Hi @Sven-Michael Stube,
I am not actually clear with this point of yours. "The measurement is called twice, because the view is added before android has measured everything properly."

Can you please direct me where can I find details about these measure calls and its working for a better understanding?

Comment: It could be that it solves the issue, **but** its a timing issue / race condition. So you can't be sure, what comes first, as long as you use `RunOnUiThread`. The Scheduler decides when he executes your action. Why is the number of `OnMeasure` calls critical for you? Normally, the result should not depend on the number of calls, only on the content and measure specs.

Comment: I mean, that `OnMeasure`is not meant to be called only once. http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9UCoqk4eOYs/UXOXi4Gqy5I/AAAAAAAAAG4/A8z6ociZjPY/s1600/android.png shows you the lifecycle. As you can see, the measurement is done after adding the view to the parent view (`onAttachedToWindow`) and if `requestLayout` is executed.

Comment: Am having a custom view for which 2 measure hits are happening generally. Mine is basically a table view in which width for a column can be customized. If I change the width of the column before the onAttachedToWindow is hit with a value apart from the default value, I will apply that new width during the first layout pass only (for performance improvement to avoid updating whenever measure is hit). So that the view will be measured and arranged with updated values during the second measure pass.

Comment: Have you measured the performance impact? Does a user notice the difference? You should not do premature optimization :)

Comment: Yes it had a performance impact and that is why I had moved the code to Layout instead of doing them in measure itself. On seeing the lifecycle I got a clear picture of how views are arranged in Android. Probably I will now try to move my code to measure with some conditions to retrict it being executed all times.

Comment: But I do have a serious doubt, Will calling request layout for a view will trigger measure of its parent?

Say I have a CustomView -> CustomScrollView -> Container. 
Now when I try to scroll my container vertically I change a property called offset, when it gets changed I call the RequestLayout() for the container so that the child views inside my container can be rearranged. But doing this makes a call to the OnMeasure of the Parent CustomView in recent days. Am not sure why? Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Yes. [requestLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()) causes a layout pass for the **view tree** and this makes totally sense. Because with request layout you say: My view may not fit into its current bounds anymore.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict the Parent's measure call when calling RequestLayout() for a view?

This was not happening for us before and we experience this only in the recent times. May be because of Layout updations in Xamarin.Android. Is there a way to make only measure the current view that is called RequestLayout and not its parent.

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe some hacky stuff. I don't think that is has something to do with xamarin.